# How to get the xml attribute values?

Tags: xml, vb6

Say I have some xml. How to get the attribute value using VB?

Comment: Maybe you should give more detail? How do you load the XML now, or are you doing anything with the XML right now at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using the MSXML library?

The following code will output all attribute values of the children nodes. The XML in this case is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<documents>
  <document id="12345" created="2002-09-24" owner="Andy" />
</documents>
```

So the output will show the values for id, created and owner.

Here's the code :-

```
    Dim XML As String
    Dim objXML As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim objElem As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    Dim objSub As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

    XML = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><documents><document id=""12345"" created=""2002-09-24"" owner=""Andy"" /></documents>"

    If Not objXML.LoadXML(XML) Then
        Err.Raise objXML.parseError.ErrorCode, , objXML.parseError.reason
    End If

    Set objElem = objXML.selectSingleNode("//documents")

    For Each objSub In objElem.childNodes
        Debug.Print objSub.nodeName

        If objSub.Attributes.length > 0 Then

        For i = 0 To objSub.Attributes.length - 1

            Debug.Print objSub.Attributes(i).nodeName & " - " & objSub.Attributes(i).nodeValue

        Next i

        End If

    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to have a look at this:

http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp